# Problem with Selenium on WhatsApp Web: unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, whatsapp

I want to use selenium on python to automatically send messages to contacts via WhatsApp web, but am getting this Error:

```sh
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@title= "contact1"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

This is my code:

```py
msg = 'good morning' 
count = 1 

names = ['contact1', 'contact2']

for name in names:
    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title= "{}"]'.format(name))
    user.click()
    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2WovP')

    for i in range(count):
        msg_box.send_keys(msg)
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_35EW6')
        button.click()
```

Comment: Try to wait for the element, use wait or add time sleep seconds

Comment: Tried with wait, its giving a TimeoutException error.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer blow solution

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@title="{0}"]'.format(name))))
```

Note: you have to include below imports to your solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks. This is still giving the TimeoutException error for certain contacts. The script seems to run fine and messages get sent to certain contacts but not all. Possibly this only works for contacts I recently chatted with on whatsapp.

Comment: Check presence of iframe while locating your element